# Can a csproj detect if using `dotnet` or `msbuild`/`devenv` for conditions?

Tags: msbuild, csproj, dotnet-cli

We have a solution that contains some WiX 3 projects that break commands like `dotnet restore` and `dotnet test` when the old style csproj tries to import `Wix.CA.targets` (https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/5627). `dotnet restore` seems to be essential since newer versions of Paket use it, and we want some .NET 8 projects within the same sln/repository root.

I don't think `Wix.CA.targets` does anything important for package restore and it is not a unit test, we are still using VS or MSBuild to do the actual build.

Is there some condition we can use in a `.csproj` file to detect when it is being loaded by a `dotnet ...` and exclude the import?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WixCATargetsPath Condition=" '$(WixCATargetsPath)' == '' ">C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.CA.targets</WixCATargetsPath>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>
  ...
  <Import Project="$(WixCATargetsPath)" Condition="NotDotnetCommand" />
</Project>
```

```
> dotnet restore demo.sln
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.CA.targets(42,5): error MSB4062: The "ReadRegistry" task
could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\WixTasks.dll. Could not load
 file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
'. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the ass
embly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microso
ft.Build.Framework.ITask. [C:\Demo\Wix\Wix.csproj]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a built-in property that will tell you that your project is being run via the `dotnet` tool.

However, you can get the full command line with `$([System.Environment]::CommandLine)`.

```xml
<Project>
  <Target Name="CmdLine">
    <Message Text="$([System.Environment]::CommandLine)"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

If this project is named example.proj, you can test running it with the following commands:

```
msbuild Example.proj
```

```
dotnet build Example.proj /v:n
```

```
dotnet msbuild Example.proj /v:n
```

In my testing on Windows, the `msbuild` command showed `msbuild` as the executable but the `dotnet` commands showed `"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.101\dotnet.dll"` as the executable.

e.g.

```
"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.101\dotnet.dll" build Example.proj /v:n
```

Still, you could initialize an `isDotnetCommand` property based on if the executable in the command line contains `dotnet`.

Comment: It seems when running `dotnet restore demo.sln` it ends up using `"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.101\MSBuild.dll"` actually, which still fails that import (not "proper" MSBuild?), so checking for anything under `dotnet\sdk` seems good. Definitely a bit of a hack but looks like will work until ready to remove these old WiX 3 projects.

Comment: The `dotnet` tool embeds `msbuild` but may be creating a sub-process, hence a DLL as the executable. SLN files are not MSBuild files. When passed a SLN file, MSBuild creates a 'metaproj' for the SLN.  ([MSBUILDEMITSOLUTION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-build-specific-targets-in-solutions-by-using-msbuild-exe?view=vs-2022#troubleshooting) can be set to save a `.sln.metaproj` file.) The reason for `msbuild.dll` instead of `dotnet.dll` may be the SLN handling.